# How to create configMap with .env with Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, kustomize

I've a NextJS app which needs a .env file mounted. I usually do this with providing a configMap:

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: frontend-configmap
  namespace: default
data:
  .env: |-
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://my.domain.com
    API_URL=http://my.domain.com
```

But how to do this with Kustomize?

I try it with `envs`, but how do I get the values inside?

```yaml
configMapGenerator:
  - name: frontend-configmap
    envs:
      - .env
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have `.env` file created first. And ideally even creating configmaps should be based on the existing file (below are examples for `kustomize` and `kubectl --from-file`).

Then there are two options how to create a configmap:

- create `.env` file with environment variables within (which is your example configmap)
- create a configmap with environment variables from `.env` file (each variable is a separate key)

**Test structure**:

```
$ tree -a
.
├── .env
└── kustomization.yaml


$ cat .env # same as your test data

NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://my.domain.com
API_URL=http://my.domain.com
```

---

**configmap with `.env` file with envvars inside:**

`kustomization.yaml` with an additional option :

```
$ cat kustomization.yaml 

configMapGenerator:
  - name: frontend-configmap
    files: # using files here as we want to create a whole file
      - .env
generatorOptions:
  disableNameSuffixHash: true # use a static name
```

`disableNameSuffixHash` - disable appending a content hash suffix to the names of generated resources, see [generator options](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/generatorOptions.md#generator-options).

And all left is to run it:

```
$ kustomize build .

apiVersion: v1
data:
  .env: | # you can see it's a file with context within
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://my.domain.com
    API_URL=http://my.domain.com
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: frontend-configmap
```

The same result can be achieved by running using `--from-file` option:

```
$ kubectl create cm test-configmap --from-file=.env --dry-run=client -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
data:
  .env: |
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://my.domain.com
    API_URL=http://my.domain.com
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: test-configmap
```

---

**configmap with envvars as keys within:**

```
$ cat kustomization.yaml 

configMapGenerator:
  - name: frontend-configmap
    envs: # now using envs to create a configmap with envvars as keys inside
      - .env
generatorOptions:
  disableNameSuffixHash: true # use a static name
```

Run it to see the output:

```
$ kustomize build .

apiVersion: v1
data: # you can see there's no file and keys are created directly
  API_URL: http://my.domain.com
  NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: http://my.domain.com
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: frontend-configmap
```

Same with `kubectl` and `--from-env-file` option:

```
$ kubectl create cm test-configmap --from-env-file=.env --dry-run=client -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
data:
  API_URL: http://my.domain.com
  NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: http://my.domain.com
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: test-configmap
```

---

**More details:**

- [configMapGenerator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/#configmapgenerator)

---

**Edit - use already existing configmap.yaml**

If `configmap` already exists, then it's possible to reference to it from `kustomization.yaml` (as mentioned in comment, `kustomize` is a template engine and using it with this direct reference only without any transformations doesn't really make sense. [Here](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/guides/example/multi_base/) is one of the examples of why you need to use `kustomize`).

```
$ tree
.
├── cm.yaml
└── kustomization.yaml
```

`cm.yaml` has exactly the same config from the question.

```
$ cat kustomization.yaml
 
resources:
- cm.yaml
namePrefix: test- # used namePrefix for demo purpose (you can omit it as well)
```

Building this and getting the same `configmap` with `.env` file inside:

```
$ kustomize build .

apiVersion: v1
data:
  .env: |-
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://my.domain.com
    API_URL=http://my.domain.com
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-frontend-configmap # name with prefix as it was setup for demo
  namespace: default
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. To understand you correctly: it's not possible to "bake in" my vars-file into the `kustomization.yml` itself (like in my very first code snippet? I *have to* either create an extra `.env` and consume that in `kustomization.yml` file OR use a "regular" `configMap`?

Comment: @Jan you can use it very similar to the regular `configMap` but `kustomize` a template engine and it doesn't really make sense to use it this way + at this point it will be more `IaC` approach when you have file with environment data (it can be different envs) and `kustomizations`. I added a link with a good example or another option - [kustomize components](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/components.md).

Comment: @Jan Forgot to mention - I added a last block in my answer which covers your question without creating an `.env` file, but again, ideal case is to create a file and separate all configurations so you can edit only one file and reduce amount of potential mistakes and so on.